# I can not get pigments highlighting for Python to work in my Sphinx documentation

Tags: python-sphinx, pygments

I've tried adding `highlight_language` and `pygments_style` in the `config.py` and also tried various ways I found online inside the `.rst` file. Can anyone offer any advice on how to get the syntax highlighting working?

Comment: Please show us exactly what you have tried. What did you expect and what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it turns out that program arguments aren't highlighted (the test I was using)